# Set value when row is maximum in group by - Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to create a column (is_max) that has either 1 if a column B is the maximum in a group of values of column A or 0 if it is not.

Example:

[Input]

```
A B 
1 2
2 3
1 4
2 5
```

[Output]

```
A B is_max
1 2   0 
2 5   0
1 4   1
2 3   0
```

What I'm trying:

```
df['is_max'] = 0
df.loc[df.reset_index().groupby('A')['B'].idxmax(),'is_max'] = 1
```

Comment: "create a column that has either 1 if the element is the maximum in a group of values or 0 if it is not."  needs clarification.  "The element"?  Which element? For every row of the new column, there are two elements to consider.  Which one do you mean?  Also, I can't see the logic of your examples.  Did you mean to put the `is_max` 1 next to the 5 instead of the 4?  Or perhaps the 5 as well as the 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I make assumption A is your group now that you did not state

```
df['is_max']=(df['B']==df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('max')).astype(int)
```

or

```
df1.groupby('A')['B'].apply(lambda x: x==x.max()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Yes, I changed wording to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

Fix your code by remove the `reset_index`

```
df['is_max'] = 0
df.loc[df.groupby('A')['B'].idxmax(),'is_max'] = 1
df
Out[39]: 
   A  B  is_max
0  1  2       0
1  2  3       0
2  1  4       1
3  2  5       1
```